# What are Qualifiers in the C language?

Tags: c, qualifiers

I am reading some text at this url:

https://cs.senecac.on.ca/~btp100/pages/content/varia_p.html

In the section 'Qualifiers', they say:

"We can qualify the int type to be sure that it contains a minimum number of bits"
....
A short contains at least 16 bits:
....

I don't understand this, what does "qualify the int type" mean and why "A short contains at least 16 bits".

Can anybody elaborate on this please?
Thanks all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Qualifiers to indicate what size of number you want to store inside your int.  Think the exact size varies by implementation of C, but typically it's as follows.

`short int a; //  16 bits, range -32,768 to 32,767`

`unsigned short int b; //  16 bits, range 0 to 65,535`

`unsigned int c; //  32 bits, range 0 to 4,294,967,295`

`int d; //  32 bits, range -2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647`

`long int d; //  32 bits, range -2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647 (minimum requirement, can be higher on 64bit systems)`

Answer (score 13):

Qualifier is an extra name given to either variables or functions , showing an extra quality or extra meaning for that variable or function. like Dr in Dr Arun Kumar

Qualifiers for variables are (TYPE qualifiers): `signed`, `unsigned`, `long`, `short`, `long long`, `const`, `volatile`, `static`, `auto`, `extern`, `register`

Qualifiers for functions are: `static`, `extern`, `inline`

Comment: Its good to verify always if its a question for terminology. They may defy intuition.

Answer (score 5):

the keywords `short`, `long`, `unsigned`, `signed`, etc are called qualifiers. The order of qualifiers is irrelevant, for example

```
short int signed x; // means signed short int x, at least 16 bits :)
```

In this line you have qualified the `int` type with `short` and `signed` qualifiers

Comment: They are in fact called "type specifiers".  In C, the qualifiers are `const`, `restrict`, and `volatile`.

Comment: @Deitrich: Yes, you are right, but apparently the book of OP means these by qualifiers

Answer (score 1):

Some keywords change the behaviour of the "int" type. These are known as qualifier. Examples include "short", "long", "unsigned", "const", "volatile". Therefore if we qualify the "int" with "short" we know that the variable contains at least 16 bits:

```
short int var;
```

Comment: don't mix things, `short`, `long` and `unsigned` are not qualifiers in the terminology of C. Qualifiers are `const`, `volatile`, `restrict` and in the upcoming standard `_Atomic`.

Answer (score 1):

Just for clarification by ISO standard [C11](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf)

- Storage-class Specifiers (6.7.1): `typedef`, `extern`, `static`, `_Thread_local`, `auto`, `register`.
- Type Specifiers (6.7.2): `void`, `char`, `short`, `int`, `long`, `float`, `double`, `signed`, `unsigned`, `_Bool`, `_Complex`, atomic-type-specifier `_Atomic (`*type name*`)`, struct-or-union-specifier (`struct` and `union`), enum-specifier (`enum`), typedef-name (`typedef` + something).
- Type Qualifiers (6.7.3): `const`, `restrict`, `volatile`, `_Atomic`.

The `_Atomic` type qualifier is not the same thing as the `_Atomic` type specifier.

Answer (score 0):

Logically, an integer is any whole number, from negative infinity to positive infinity.

It would be nice in C/C++ to be able to declare an int and use it to store any integer, but unfortunately there have to be limits on the range of values you can store in an int data type.

C/C++ lets you declare short, int or long variable types which can store 2^16, 2^32 and 2^64 distinct whole numbers respectively.

To say that the int type is qualified is the same as saying it's been limited to hold a smaller subset of whole numbers.

Comment: -1: ints are not always 32 bits, and longs are not always 64 bits. shorts are **at least** 16 bits (may be more). Also some qualifiers to not affect the number of bits of storage.