# Is it possible that a declarator has zero declaration specifier?

Tags: c, declaration, specifier

Regarding the statement;

> Every object declaration in C and C++ has two principal parts: a sequence of zero or more declaration specifiers, and a sequence of one or more declarators, separated by commas.
>   For example:
>   [image]

Does *zero specifier* means declaring a variable named `a` as

```
a;
```

and not

```
int a;
```

?
I tried this with an example

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
     x = 9; 
     printf("%d\n", x);

return 0; 
}
```

and this is giving an error:

```
[Error] 'x' undeclared (first use in this function)
```

Comment: Where did you get that statement from?  It's clearly wrong.

Comment: It might have been true for pre-standardization C, which has the "implicit int rule". Regardless, this should never have been used.

Comment: @CarlNorum; I get this from [here](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=4&cad=rja&ved=0CEYQFjAD&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.dansaks.com%2Farticles%2F1998-06%2520Placing%2520const%2520in%2520Declarations.pdf&ei=rXrpUbKnAcrMrQfUjoCQBQ&usg=AFQjCNG8M1tyIyLS1jJ-bX5MXZ-TcjgYQg&sig2=5pdYOyGUhbjWUp32yxLQvg&bvm=bv.49478099,d.bmk)

Comment: Sounds like a pre C89 C, valid then, but with C89 and forward not allowed.  Nice that you were ready with the reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was possible in c89 with the implicit `int` rule but you needed at least a qualifer or a storage class specifier.

```
auto x = 3;   /* allowed in c89, not valid in c99 */

static y = 4; /* allowed in c89, not valid in c99 */

const z = 5;  /* allowed in c89 , not valid in c99*/

a;      /* not valid in c89, c99 without a prior declaration */

b = 6;  /* not valid in c89, c99 without a prior declaration */
```

Comment: But all of these declaration used an specifier!

Comment: @haccks `const` is a qualifier not a specifier.

Comment: I read about qualifiers that **it alters the characteristics of the data type, such as its `size` or `sign`**. What about `signed`, Is it qualifier or specifier?

Comment: qualifiers do not alter size or sign, you are talking about a type specifier. `signed` is a type specifier.

Comment: I think this time you are wrong ouah; Read this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5103836/2455888).

Comment: @hackks No, I don't think I'm wrong. Type qualifiers are `const`,  `volatile`, `restrict` and `_Atomic`. See c11, 6.7.3 Type qualifiers.

Answer (score 1):

Wherever you got that statement from, it's wrong.  You have to have at least one *declaration-specifier* for a declaration to be valid.  Here's the relevant bit from the standard (it's an image because I couldn't make markdown behave):

[image: C11 standard about declarations]

Comment: I get this from a [magazine snippet](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=4&cad=rja&ved=0CEYQFjAD&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.dansaks.com%2Farticles%2F1998-06%2520Placing%2520const%2520in%2520Declarations.pdf&ei=rXrpUbKnAcrMrQfUjoCQBQ&usg=AFQjCNG8M1tyIyLS1jJ-bX5MXZ-TcjgYQg&sig2=5pdYOyGUhbjWUp32yxLQvg&bvm=bv.49478099,d.bmk)(JUNE 1998 EMBEDDED SYSTEMS PROGRAMMING)