# Is signed/unsigned part of base type or is it a qualifier

Tags: c++, c, qualifiers

[Wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_qualifier) claimed the qualifiers in C++ are `const` and `volatile`.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5103836/3004698) tells `unsigned`, `unsigned` and `short`, etc. are also qualifiers. Though the the question did mention it is about the C, the [Wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_qualifier) does not tell so either on the C side. For C the qualifiers are `const`, `volatile`, `restrict` and `_Atomic`.

And the expanding message box of the `qualifier` Tag of Stack Overflow says

> A qualifier adds an extra "quality", such as specifying volatility or
>   constness of a variable

"Add an extra quality", from the quotation, singed/unsigned seems meet the condition, it added the restricted extra quality to an integer so that it can hold positive number only or the negative one as well.

I'm confused a bit on this issue at the moment. For **C** and **C++**, is `signed`, `unsigned` and `short`, etc. counted as **part of the base type** or the **type qualifier**? And please elaborate if the rules are different in C and C++.

Comment: _"For every type other than reference and function, the type system supports three additional cv-qualified versions of that type (const, volatile, and const volatile)."_ See: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/type and http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/types  Also this is probably different for C and C++.

Comment: `signed` and `unsigned` cannot be used with any type. C11 `_Generic` is a switch-case by type. It discards `const` and `volatile` qualitfier, but not signess. But does it really matter? You can check the standard, but even then it is still just a word game.

Comment: @RichardCritten seems you given 2 same resource url, I guess you mean http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/type

Comment: @SLN corrected thanks should now say .../type and .../types

Comment: A qualifier doesn't change what the possible values of a type are. The elements of `int` and `unsigned int` only partially overlap.

Comment: `singed` is for very hot variables.

Comment: @Eljay what is hot variables?

Comment: It's  somewhat important to distinguish between "qualifier" as defined by the C++ standard, and "qualifier" as defined in a dictionary. Some texts appear to use "qualifier" as a synonym to "specifier", which is not the Standard meaning.

Comment: @SLN • [singed](https://www.google.com/search?num=1&q=Dictionary#dobs=singed)

Comment: Pictorial representation of the universe of types in C++, and how they are classified: http://howardhinnant.github.io/TypeHiearchy.pdf

Comment: @HowardHinnant thx, that's a good illustration!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In both C and C++, `signed`, `unsigned`, `short` and `long` are *type specifier*. They can be combined with `int`, even implicitly. `signed` and `unsigned` can also be combined with `char`.

In contrast, qualifiers can be applied to almost any type. (There's no `int& const` type, only `int const&`)

Answer (score 2):

According to the C11 standard ([§6.7.3](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.2)), the type *qualifiers* are `const`, `restrict`, `volatile` and `_Atomic`. `signed` and `unsigned` fall under type *specifiers* ([§6.7.2](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.3)).